# MSVC12 thinks aggregate derived from std::array is not pod

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-assert

Given the following

```
#include <array>

struct litmus final : std::array<unsigned char, 16>
{
};

static_assert(std::is_pod<std::array<unsigned char, 16> >::value, "not pod");

// this fails on MSVC:
static_assert(std::is_pod<litmus>::value, "not pod");
```

The following compilers agree that `litmus` is pod:

- clang++ version 3.5 (trunk 198621) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7add7a2fe58a7e38
- g++ 4.8.1 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74cfe97f06c8c128

However, MSVC12 (VS2013 RTM) maintains that the second assert fails.

1. Who's right?
2. Is there any trick to make MSVC treat the class as pod?

> **EDIT** For information: `is_trivially_copyable<litmus>` returns true-ness on MSVC. This might be useful for many cases where actual POD-ness isn't strictly required.

Comment: FWIW I looked at the specification of *standard-layout class* and *POD struct* in section 9 of The Standard, and I agree `litmus` should be a POD. Can't help with a workaround though.

Comment: didn't even know you could use 'final' like that, thanks !

Comment: You could specialise `std::is_pod` for `litmus` to return true, assuming your use case is actually as simple as this example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. GCC and Clang; that class is POD.
2. That depends on what *exactly* you mean with "make MSVC treat the class as pod." If you mean the compiler internals, then no. However, you can (in practice) specialise the trait for `litmus`:

   ```
   namespace std {

   template <>
   struct is_pod<litmus> : std::true_type
   {};

   }
   ```

   Note that going strictly by the standard, this gives undefined behaviour (thanks @R.MartinhoFernandes for pointing this out). However, as a compiler-specific workaround, I'd expect it to work. Use without any warranty.

Comment: To be strictly correct: **no, you cannot** specialise the trait for it. Making `std::is_pod` lie not only not intended as a feature but it is *explicitly forbidden*. However, this being a compiler-specific workaround, it's sorta fine.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thanks, amended. I wasn't aware trait type specialisations are explicitly forbidden; it does makes sense, though.

Comment: @Angew To me it's about safety. I don't mind if the assert needs to be commented. I just need to know that the class is bitwise-copyable. How can I know this to be the case, if the compiler's `is_pod` trait _doesn't tell me it's safe_?

Comment: @sehe The standard tells you it *should be* safe. Whether the MSVC bug is in the trait only, or in its internal understanding, would have to be tested. But I'd expect the class to be bitwise-copyable.

Comment: @Angew Yeah. I _suspect_ the same. However, thinking about testing this breaks my head. You can't really devise a test case that excludes undefined behaviour with authority...

Comment: @sehe: If you want to know whether it's trivially copyable, use `is_trivially_copyable` rather than `is_pod`. (Assuming your compiler gets that one right).

Comment: I'd say the proper workaround would be your own `is_trivially_copyable` which defaults to `std::is_trivially_copyable` but with template specializations for cases you know are wrong.

Comment: @MSalters yes. It appears I was really looking for `is_trivially_copyable`; I was being overly specific. That solves it for my use case.