# Check for empty destructor

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, sfinae

Is there a way to use templates, macros, or a combination of both to check for an empty destructor inside a class and inside the classes it inherits from? (**is_trivially_destructible** does not produce what I need).

```
class Test
{
   public:
   ~Test(){};
};

class Temp2 : public Test
{
};
```

Comment: The short answer is that no, it's not possible.

Comment: ...but what are you trying to achieve as a bigger picture?

Comment: @Jefffrey I know that some compilers can remove loops calling empty-destructors, but I want to know if I can detect an empty destructor.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg from your comment I sense that there is a long answer of yes. If that is so, can you point me to some resources I can read on how to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately the long answer is the same, but much more technical. And while the compiler can detect empty functions, there is no facility in the standard library (or even as any compiler extension that I know of) that can check for it in any way.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. I imagine it has to do with not knowing size of functions? Posted this, while you posted yours. If you make a normal post I will accept your answer.

Comment: @user985611 I'd guess that the compilers can choose *not* to call the destructor if the destructor doesn't *do* anything. That's different from being *empty*. For example, `struct s { unique_ptr<int> m; ~s() {} };` has a non-trivial, but "empty" dtor. It's a bit unfortunate that an empty dtor that would otherwise be trivial (if defaulted) is not considered trivial, but OTOH you can always use `=default` in these cases. I'd recommend just use `is_trivially_destructible` and default those empty dtors.

Comment: @dyp That is what I decided to do. The case you pointed out is exactly the reason why I want to be able to detect empty dtors.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor "being empty" doesn't mean anything, as any non-pod member objects will /implicitly/ be destructed there by the compiler (even if no destructor is declared).

So, in fact what you want is likely

- `std::is_pod<T>::value`

  Beware: [MSVC gets it wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968200/msvc12-thinks-aggregate-derived-from-stdarray-is-not-pod) (e.g. for `struct X : std::array<int, 4> {}` which *is* pod)
- `std::is_trivial<T>::value`

The idea is that a constructor can be skipped only if the constructor doesn't do anything magic either. Construction and destruction are designed to be in perfect balance, so you know the destructor is trivial if the construction side is too.

Comment: A *trivially copyable* class needs to have a trivial dtor. So, `is_pod` and `is_trivial` (which both require *trivially copyable*) don't help if the OP rejects `is_trivially_destructible`.

Comment: @dyp Oh. Gee. I assumed "is_trivially_destructible does not produce what I need" mostly made sense because that trait wouldn't exist (I hadn't heard of it). Silly me